# Is it possible for outside traffic to access my deployment inside Minikube?

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

Kubernetes newbie here. Just want to get my fundamental understanding correct. Minikube is known for local development and is it possible for connection outside (not just outside cluster) to access the pods I have deployed in minikube?

I am running my minikube in ec2 instance so I started my minikube with command `minikube start --vm-driver=none`, which means running minikube with Docker, no VM provisioned. My end goal is to allow connection outside to reach my pods inside the cluster and perform POST request through the pod (for example using Postman).

> If yes, I also have my service resource applied using `kubectl apply
>   -f` into my minikube using NodePort in yaml file. Also, I also wish to understand `port`, `nodePort`, and `targetPort` correctly. `port` is
>   the port number assigned to that particular service, `nodePort` is the
>   port number on the node (in my case is my ec2 instance private IP),
>   `targetPort` is the port number equivalent to the `containerPort` I've
>   assigned in yaml of my deployment. Correct me if I am wrong in this statement.

Thanks.

Comment: the problem is solved and proven that minikube can accept traffic outside (from internet) with proper configuration of NodePort as well as LoadBalancer. I messed up my targetPort that's why I couldn't get proper response from my deployment to my postman. Another tips: to curl internally with proper curl POST request, you can use postman to create that with proper format pressing the `code` button.  Thanks to @harsh reaffirming my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can do that

as you have started the minikube with :

```
minikube start --vm-driver=none
```

`nodePort` is the port that a client outside of the cluster will "see". nodePort is opened on every node in your cluster via kube-proxy. You can use nodePort to access the application from outside world. Like `https://loadbalancerIP:NodePort`

`port` is the port your service listens on inside the cluster. Let's take this example:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: test-service
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 8080
    targetPort: 8070
    nodePort: 31222
    protocol: TCP 
  selector:
    component: test-service-app
```

From inside k8s cluster this service will be reachable via http://test-service.default.svc.cluster.local:8080 (service to service communication inside your cluster) and any request reaching there is forwarded to a running pod on targetPort 8070.

`tagetPort` is also by default the same value as port if not specified otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Harsh. I just had spin up a 'utils' pod with basic utils such as ping, telnet, curl etc. I can ping from 'utils' pod to my deployed pod IP (not service internal IP) but I couldn't telnet to the pod IP with the port number I have stated in my deployment yaml. 

I still doubt I can access the deployment inside cluster as the `EXTERNAL-IP` column still appears to be  `<none>` .

Comment: To supplement my previous comment, I could not telnet from the 'utils' pod to my service `CLUSTER-IP` with either TYPE of cluster ip or NodePort. 

This is how I spin up the 'utils' pod. `kubectl run --rm utils -it --generator=run-pod/v1 --image arunvelsriram/utils bash`

Comment: i would better create the yaml files and apply for the service and deployment.

Comment: @rick this is probably best documentation you can follow. https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/

Comment: instead of telnet try using curl only.

Comment: now i can internally curling into my cluster within the same local machine, my mistake is curling into wrong ports. However i still couldnt curl from outside local machine (ec2)

Comment: you can use now loadbalancer service to get the Ip address and curl the service.